# Do Muslims understand the English word "god" specific to Allah? What's right response to "may God be with you"?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, non-muslim, christianity

Do Muslims understand the English word "god" specific to be Allah, or at least a neutral word not in exclusive use by any religion? If so, may I assume the God referred in "may God be with you" could be Allah, hence react at ease?

However, if Muslims understand the English word "god" is for Christian use exclusively, what's the best reaction for Muslims when receiving a blessing in pure good will from such different religion?

*(Original question was a two-part one that begins with asking if the concept of "may God bless you (be with you)" exist in Islam. That is solved, Thank you.)*

Comment: UmH according to my "Invocation from The Quran and Sunnah" booklet to a non-Muslim you only say Wa'alaikum (i.e. and upon you) Al-Bukhari, from Al-asqalani, fath Al-Bari 42/11, Muslim 4/1705.

Comment: in Arabic: god = ila. The god = Allah. Thus god/ila means any god including all the false gods. Allah mean the god, i.e. the God of Abraham/Moses/Jesus , the only god. in writting you can get away with it by having capital "G" for the God and small "g" for any god, but you cannot say this in speach. But mostly I find the context of the speak just gives away what you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Allah is God in English and it is understood in this fashion by all Muslims. 
"God is with you" "God bless you" all is taken as "Allah is with you" and "Allah bless you" and vice versa. Besides, Muslims, Jews and Christians are children of Abraham; from same family. Peace on humanity.